# How to insert blank rows in excel based on another column value

Tags: excel, rows, vba

In excel i have two column,one is the url and in second column i have numeric values and i want to insert blank rows based on second column numeric value.Values are just like this

```
first column           Second Column
www.google.com          25
www.weslez.com          10
```

My reqirment is to insert 25 blank rows below first row and 10 blank rows below second row..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
Sub InsertRows()

    Dim End_Row As Long, n As Long, Ins As Long
    End_Row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = End_Row To 1 Step -1

        Ins = Cells(n, "B").Value

        If Ins > 0 Then Range("B" & n + 1 & ":B" & n + Ins).EntireRow.Insert

    Next n
End Sub
```

Regards

Xsi